# Cannot find page even if page is in the package

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm having a problem with  my `Errai GWT` app which I get this error when the page tries to `TransitionTo` a page, say `FormsPage`:

```
No page with a widget type of com.mycompany.myproject.client.local.FormsPage exists
```

Even if the FormsPage is there in the package and there is no-compile time error (so it was able to locate the page) in:

```
TransitionTo<FormsPage> formsPage;
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: It is probably irrelevant to add facebook and java tags.

Comment: Yup, my bad, that was a tag from my previous post...

Comment: Three questions: which version of Errai are you using when you get that error, what does the Java code for FormsPage look like, and which package is FormsPage in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the include `@Page` annotation in the "page" class.

So adding this on it resolved the issue.